# CanCan not authorizing nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have a Ticket model and a TicketReply model:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :replies, :class_name => "TicketReply"
end

class TicketReply < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ticket, :class_name => "Ticket"
end
```

Here is my list of abilities:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)    
    can :manage, Ticket,      :userid => user.id
    can :manage, TicketReply, :ticket => { :userid => user.id }
  end
end
```

And finally my TicketRepliesController:

```
class TicketRepliesController < AuthorizedController
  load_and_authorize_resource :ticket
  load_and_authorize_resource :ticket_reply, :through => :ticket

  def create
    if @ticket_reply.valid?
      # ...
    else
     # ...
    end
  end
end
```

However, every time I try to create a ticket reply I get an unauthorized message: "You are not authorized to access this page.".

**EDIT**: I can access the `Ticket` itself fine through a `TicketsController`.

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

In the controller new and create actions, you need to wire your new ticket record with the current_user

```
class TicketRepliesController < AuthorizedController
  ... whatever code you have

  protected

  # override to do the wireing
  def build_resource
    resource = super
    resource.userid = current_user.id # wired!
    resource
  end
end
```

Now CanCan will see the link and allow!

Comment: At worst override the new and create methods to do the wiring. Let me see cancan code again maybe I find out where the building is done